# Finding Sum of total collection from datetime column

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

My database structure like :

```
collected today  created_at              updated_at
200              2017-07-02 06:20:07     2017-07-02 06:34:19
200              2017-07-02 06:34:19     2017-07-02 06:34:19
400              2017-07-03 06:34:19     2017-07-03 06:34:19
100              2017-07-05 06:34:19     2017-07-05 06:34:19
50               2017-07-02 06:34:19     2017-07-02 06:34:19
```

I wanted to find sum of collected_today every date (if day 2017-07-02 has two collected_today ie, 40+50 =90 should be shown with date),
Query should return

```
updated_at total_collection 
2017-07-02 600
```

i used following query to access the data. But it returns 0 though i have value in database on every date. What could be possible Error of the following query?

```
 $monthly_report = DB::table('transactions')
                ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(transactions.updated_at)'))
                ->sum('transactions.collected_today');
                ->select('transactions.updated_at',DB::raw('sum(collected_today)')
```

Comment: Unfortunately you are not clear. Please use more words, phrases & sentences to say what you want. Don't try to cram everything into a few words. Give a complete example. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Check the Question again .

Comment: That is better but still not very clear. Use enough words. And again: Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$data = DB::table("transactions")
    ->select('updated_at',DB::raw("SUM(collected_today) as sum"))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(updated_at)'))
    ->get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this and it works for me:

```
DB::table('transactions')
    ->selectRaw('updated_at, SUM(collected_today)')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(updated_at)'))
    ->get();
```